# Probability Venn Diagram: Class of 100 students; Violin and Piano

Tags: probability, statistics, ratio

In a class of $100$ students, $x$ students play the violin and $2x$ play the piano. If $\frac{x}{2}$ students play both the violin and the piano, and there are 3x non-piano players, find the probability of a student playing neither piano or violin.

How would you solve this question using logic, and then also algebra?

Comment: $x$ is count of players, and $3x$ is a probability? Cannot be. What mistake are you making?

Comment: That's what i thought.. 3x is not a probability... maybe its a typo.

Comment: Maybe 3x/100???

Comment: In that case the total number of players is $2x$ piano players and $3x$ non-piano players. So then $x=20$ and everything is easy: 30 piano-only, 10 both, 10 violin-only, so 50 players, 50 non-players.

Comment: Oh i didn't realise it was that simple - just add piano and non piano together... thanks! Would you like to post an answer? Or should i just answer it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the non-piano probability is $\frac{3x}{100}$ instead(probabilities cannot be integers $>1$), we get that there are $3x$ non-piano players, so $2x + 3x = 5x$ people in total (piano and non-piano are complementary). So $x=20$.

In that case there are $10$ violin-only players, $10$ play both piano and violin while $30$ play piano only. So we have $50$ players of either instrument and $50$ that play neither. So the asked for probability is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

The total number of students is 100.
All students come under the 2 categories of either piano players, or non-piano players.
Therefore:

Total number of students = piano players + non-piano players

```
        100 = 5x
          x = 20
```

We know that: *x* students play the violin, 2 *x* play the piano, x/2 play both.
Violinists = 20
Pianists = 40

Total musicians = (20+40) - 10 = 50

Therefore:
Pr(Student playing NO instrument) = 50/100 = 0.5

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.